# Parsing json where field can have two different types with gson or jackson

Tags: android, json, gson, jackson, deserialization

I have json with field that contains two different types.

```
"fields":[{"value":"ZIELONE OKO"},{"value":{"@nil":"true"}}]
```

I have problem with deserializing these. My class with model contains:

```
private String value;
```

And I simply need to translate {"@nil":"true"} into null. Right now I get error:

```
The JsonDeserializer StringTypeAdapter failed to deserialized json object {"@nil":"true"} given the type class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, I would change code that produces that odd JSON: shouldn't second value just be JSON null? I guess it is being produced by some complex process, starting with XML (which must use 'isNul' to differentiate between null String and empty String).

But if that is not possible, I think both Jackson and Gson would require either custom deserializer; or to first bind to a generic Map and then handle value oddities explicitly. In second case, you just declare type to bind to as Map (possible with generic type info using reference; but that should be optional).

Comment: I know changing json would be optimal but it's out of discussion. It seems I need some sort of custom deserializator but question is how?

Comment: Documentations for both GSon and Jackson show examples of custom serializers, deserializers. For Jackson (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers), Gson (http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ), for example.

Comment: @StaxMan's link to Gson custom serialization/deserialization has changed: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Comment: More info Gson custom serialization/deserialization [https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter(java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object](http://alturl.com/wq9r4) (sorry about the use of url shortener, but stack overflow didn't like javadoc links)